# Newly published app 'ClassNotFoundException' on package name

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, runtimeexception

Below is a crash report for a newly published app. I tested purchasing it with a google account that is listed as a tester, could that have anything to do with it? The stack strace says the package name in the path has a ' -1 ' on the end of it?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123/com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.MainActivity" on path: /mnt/asec/com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123-1/pkg.apk
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2060)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.MainActivity" on path: /mnt/asec/com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123-1/pkg.apk
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2051)
... 11 more



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123" 
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/game_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service android:name="com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.MyMusicService" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>        
    <activity
        android:name="com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.Preferences"
        android:label="@string/set_preferences"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.GameSelector"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game_selector"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.Game2Show"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game2_show"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.Game2Try"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game2_try"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.Game1Show"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game1_show"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.Game1Try"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game1_try"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Package name having -1 is normal. Did you use proguard when signing the apk?

Comment: I didn't. I saw that it is recommended when using the licensing library and I did download the tool but as this is my first application I was unsure about using it and didn't think it was required?

Comment: It's not required. If you had used it, it may have been your problem. While debugging, I'm sure it worked fine on your device but have you tried installing your signed APK prior to pushing to the play store?

Comment: Also, problems like this are very often from a mistake in your AndroidManifest.xml when adding Activities. Have you used fully qualified names when declaring your Activities there?

Comment: The lite version works from the play store. I added my XML

Comment: I just downloaded the apps installer application and am going to install my signed apk now. I didn't realize this was possible. I have so much to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I need to do a Project --> Clean.

Forgetting to do that first when something isn't working (ie. before I try EVERYTHING else!) is going to turn me into a crazy person...

Comment: + 1 for despite the excitement coming back and posting an answer. cheerz

Comment: Hah, thanks! I was just thinking about this today when I spent another 20 minutes before cleaning the project and finding that was all I needed.